# PYODBC/Windows - How do I avoid typing my password in code?

Tags: python, pyodbc

I'm trying to set up my Windows environment, so I don't need to pass through my password every time I connect to the database using `pyodbc` to make sure my password is not visible in my code. See code snipppet below:

```
                          cnxn = pyodbc.connect
                          ('DRIVER={vertica'+\
                          '};SERVER=servername'+\
                          ';DATABASE=dbname'+\
                          ';UID='+\
                          ';PWD='')
```

Any suggestions on how I should edit my environment to set this up?

I've already tried updating Data sources in the Windows ODBC datadources, also tried `"Truested_connection = yes"`.

The error I get when I remove the UID and password is below:

`Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Vertica][VerticaDSII] (160) Connection attempt failed: could not translate host name "jsvertica" to address: T\n (160) (SQLDriverConnect)')`

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a config.ini file with all the credentials and then read and parse it with configparser module to populate all the fields required in the pyodbc connect. 
Link to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)

They have explained it very briefly in it.